# Unable to click 2 value from the dropdown in webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

The Code is:

```
public void setRing(int index, String ringPattern) throws InterruptedException {
List<WebElement> webElementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(an.getProperty("an_ringPattern")));

webElementList.get(index).click();

List<WebElement> options = webElementList.get(index).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
  for (WebElement element : options) {
      if (element.getText().equals(ringPattern)) {
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
   }
}
```

When I execute this code in debug mode, it is working fine. It selects whatever value I pass to the method. 
But when I run this code it is not able to change the value in the drop down. It selects the value in the drop down, but it's not able to set the value.

Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Do you want to select option from proper dropdown which tag is `select`??

Comment: What do you mean with 'debug mode'. Debugger in eclipse or similar?

Comment: I have 4 dropdown and every dropdown has 4 values .I have not used select class here i get  the element the from the list. I have to set the second value in every dropdown and save it. Its working fine for first value when i am try to set other value it won't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

If the Exception `.Error message display below at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutExceptio‌​n(WebDriverWait.java‌​:80)` is being thrown, means that somehow that element is not ready on the frame, the driver is not on that frame or the xpath is wrong.
You can try to switch to the frame where the element is located, like this: `driver.switchToFrame("here goes the id of the frame");` You can inspect the ID of the frame or sometimes just passing the integer 0 works. Also, I would rather use  `wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element));` instead of `wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));`. 
When you use `presenceOfElementLocated`, you cant assure that the element is visible for the driver.

Comment: But my code is working fine when i am doing step by step (debug mode) there is no xpath error. When i execute then only it click on drop down but not the specific the value. if there is xpath issue my code not executed in debug mode.

Comment: I have check this code in chrome. The code is working fine in chrome version but it fail in FF 41.0.2 , selenium 2.47.1 version .Please let me know there is any comp ability issue in the above versions.

Comment: Please let me know how it works in FF, there is any add-on required ? How to resolve this issue in FF.

Comment: Xpath engines are different in each browser. Instead of using Xpath, use CSS selector. This should definitely work because CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit wait in selenium - WebDriverWait

Use below modified code

```
public void setRing(int index, String ringPattern) throws InterruptedException {
List<WebElement> webElementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(an.getProperty("an_ringPattern")));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60); 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(webElementList.get(index)));
webElementList.get(index).click();

List<WebElement> options = webElementList.get(index).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
  for (WebElement element : options) {
      WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);  
      wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(element));
      if (element.getText().equals(ringPattern)) {
        element.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have try explicit wait also the same issue exists. In eclpise debug mode its working fine. When i execute it does't pick the 2nd value.Error message display below at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)